# How can I use a variable variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, variable-variables

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
<?php
    $my_str = "My String";
    $str = "%my_str";

    $str = str_replace("%", "$", $str);

    echo $str;
?>
```

The above code prints '$my_str' to the screen. But I want it to print 'My String', as in the actual value of the variable $my_str

Anyone know how to do this?

The reason I want this is because I'm in the process of writing my own, very basic, parsing language so I kinda need this to be functional before I can continue.

Comment: Ok I got what I needed, eval("echo $str;"); does the trick.

I'm aware of the security risks but this page can only be accessed by the owner, so it should be fine.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 9):

```
$my_str = 'My String';
$str    = 'my_str';

echo $$str;
```

This construction is called a [variable variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the user wanted - they seem to want to perform interpolation of the string, as if it were a literal, rather than just getting the value of the variable named in the string.

Comment: Indeed this is most certainly not what I am after. I'm completely aware of how variable variables work. Thanks for your help though.

(Weird how this is voted up and the other answers, which are exactly what I was after, are voted down)

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what you were after and I don't understand why `eval` was better in this case. Anyway, if `eval` is better for you, I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 2):

eval is not necessary. Just get rid of the % and use $$str

```
<?php
    $my_str = "My String";
    $str = "%my_str";

    $str = str_replace("%", "", $str);

    echo $$str;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I want the %, as I said, I'm in the process of making a simple parsing language which processes templates. eval works great, but thanks for your help regardless!

Answer (score 2):

You could search and replace the `%var` patterns using `preg_replace` and the `e` modifier, which makes the replacement being evaluated:

```
<?php
    $my_str = "My String";
    $str = "Foo %my_str bar";

    $str = preg_replace("/%([A-Za-z_]+)/e", "$\\1", $str);

    echo $str;
?>
```

Here `preg_replace` will find `%my_str`, `\1` contains `my_str` and `"$\\1"` (the backslash needs to be escaped) becomes the value of $my_str.

However, it would maybe be cleaner to store your replacement strings in an associative array:

```
<?php
    $replacements = array(
        "my_str" => "My String",
    );
    $str = "Foo %my_str bar";

    $str = preg_replace("/%([A-Za-z_]+)/e", '$replacements["\\1"]', $str);

    echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo $$str;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP automatically parses and expands variables within [double-quoted strings](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

```
<?php
    $my_str = "My String";
    $str = "{$my_str}";

    echo $str;
?>
```

Outputs:

```
My String
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regex with the e modifier

```
$str = preg_replace("/%([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/e", '$\1', $str);
```

(This is untested, but should work)

Answer (score -1):

The behaviour you see is not surprising - expansion of variables ("interpolation") is performed on only string literals, rather than variables. If it wasn't, then it would be a large security hole (any instance of a string with $ in it that your code used would suddenly be revealing  variables).

You *can* try and fix this using eval, as in

```
eval ("\$str = \"" . str_replace("%", "\$", $str) . "\"");
```

but this pretty dangerous - if your string is from the user, then can make $str something like

```
"; system("rm -rf /"); $x = "
```

and suddenly, you're in trouble. The best solution, I believe, will be to parse out variables using your favourite methods (stripos and substring, or something more), then replace each one by hand.

Comment: Actually that code gives me errors.

 eval("\$str = \"" . str_replace("%", "$", $str) . "\";");

That works though, cheers for the help.